# Elsa Workflow - Fork (Control Flow)

Tags: httprequest, workflow, httpresponse, endpoint, elsa-workflows

Could someone please explain how Fork from Elsa Workflow works?

I have set up HTTP Endpoint. After that I send HTTP Request and I get HTTP Response in JSON format.
I want to set condition on that response (for example name='John') so that I could display only that row from database.

What Elsa activity should I use? Is Fork activity correct choice or other?

Answer (score 5):

#### Fork

The **Fork** activity simply forks workflow execution into multiple branches. When you add this activity, you specify a list of one or more branch names. These branch names will be scheduled as activity **outcomes**.

For example, if you add a Fork activity with branches `Do Some Request` and `Timeout`, the Fork activity will show these branches as outcomes.

When the Fork activity executes, **both** branches will execute. This enables scenarios where you for example want to wait for some user input or some other job to finish, but not indefinitely: you have a second branch that waits for a timeout event using e.g. the **Timer** activity.

A sample workflow that describes the usage of the **Fork** activity in a similar scenario can be found [here](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/guides/guides-document-approval#send-reminder-email-to-josh-the-approver).

That describes the use case of the Fork activity. But you will want to use the **If** activity instead.

#### If

Going back to your use case with the **HTTP Request** activity and setting a condition, what you want to use instead of **Fork** is the **If** activity.

When you connect an **If** activity to **HTTP Request**, you will be able to write a JS expression that must evaluate to `true` or `false`.

For example, let's say your **Send HTTP Request** activity performs a GET request on https://reqres.in/api/users/2

Make sure that the **Read Content** checkbox is ticked.
Also make sure to **give your Send HTTP Request activity a name**. For example, `SendHttpRequest1`.

With that in place, you can now write the following JS expression in the Condition field of the If activity:

```js
activities.SendHttpRequest1.ResponseContent().data.first_name == 'Janet'
```

Note that `activities.SendHttpRequest1.ResponseContent()` returns an `ExpandoObject` that represents the received JSON response from the demo API endpoint I used in my example.

Comment: Hello @Sipke, so grateful for your time and information about Elsa Control Flow. I was wondering how can I display the result that I get after **IF**. When I send HttpRequest (target is API which points database MS SQL Server) I connect an **IF** activity and that is the situation when I stuck. What should I do after IF to display the result which satisfies the condition from **IF**?

Comment: Same principle. If you want to e.g. display the result by sending back an HTTP response, you use the `WriteHttpResponse` activity and set its Content field to e.g. `activities.SendHttpRequest1.ResponseContent().data.first_name` to simply render the name (using the JS syntax). Better yet would be to use the Liquid syntax so you can write a more proper response (even if it is JSON). More info: https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/expressions/expressions-liquid. Let me know if you have more questions.